# Can anyone tell me why my old list has all the values which should be there only in the new list.?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, iterator

1. I am storing a list in tmp and then adding new values in list.
2. On refresh I am comparing old list with new list.
3. And if new list has new entry then generating notification but every time i find all the values in my old list.

   ```
   public void populateList(String result) {
       ArrayList<User> tmp;
       tmp = list;
       list.clear();
       try {
           JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
           for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
               JSONObject json_data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
               String NAME = json_data.getString(StaticMember.NAME);
               String STATUS = json_data.getString(StaticMember.STATUS);
               list.add(new User(NAME, STATUS));
           }
           ArrayList tmpN = list;
           compare(tmp, tmpN);
           CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
           lv.setAdapter((customAdapter));

       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

   public void compare(ArrayList list_old, ArrayList list_new) {
       try {
           Iterator<User> iterator_old = list_old.iterator();
           Iterator<User> iterator_new = list_new.iterator();

           while (iterator_new.hasNext()) {
               User user_new = iterator_new.next();
               boolean NEW = true;

               while (iterator_old.hasNext()) {
                   User user_old = iterator_old.next();
                   //Log.i(":N:"+user_new.getUsername(), ":O:"+user_old.getUsername());
                   if (user_new.getUsername().equals(user_old.getUsername())) {
                       NEW = false;
                       break;
                   }
               }
               if (NEW) {
                   generateNotification(getApplicationContext(), user_new.getUsername() + " has been added.");
                   Log.i("True", "Changed");
               }
           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: You inner while loop need to use a fresh (new) iterator on the old list. An iterator cannot be reused (you actually don't reuse it, you just go thu the old list once, and then `hasNext()` returns false).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do `tmp = list` you do not store the values of `list` in `tmp`. Instead, you simply make `tmp` reference the same object that `list` references. Later, when you modify `list`, you modify the content that `tmp` references.

Initially, `list` references the user list:

```
 list -> [user0, user1, user2]
```

After `tmp = list`, both `list` and `tmp` reference the same list:

```
 list -> [user0, user1, user2] <- tmp
```

When you call `list.clear()`, you clear the original list:

```
 list -> [] <- tmp
```

And when you add new elements to `list`, you modify the original list:

```
 list -> [newuser0] <- tmp
```

If you need to store a copy of `list` in `tmp` you need to create a new list before you modify the old one:

```
List<User> tmp = new ArrayList<>(list);
```

Note that the `User` objects stored in both lists are still the same though, so if you modify an object from one list, it will be reflected on the other.

Comment: Thank you very much. You explained very well.